# Uploading xes files to weka

Tags: weka

I want to use the tool WEKA for process prediction. Since many event logs are in the XES format I somehow need to convert XES to a WEKA-readable format. (i.e: arff, csv, json)
Is there a tool or a code I can use?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pm4py library](https://pm4py.fit.fraunhofer.de) in python to convert it into a csv.

```
import pandas as pd
from pm4py.objects.conversion.log import converter as log_converterv
dataframe = log_converter.apply(log, variant=log_converter.Variants.TO_DATA_FRAME)
dataframe.to_csv('<path_to_csv_file.csv>')
```